# Are questions without "?" valid in codereview?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I'm more active on superuser, but sometimes check vba questions also here.

I've noticed that sometimes questions contains description of the code and the code itself, but no actual question is posted. (e.g. [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/153149/comparing-two-arrays-and-printing-results-as-a-collection-of-a-class#comment291083_153149) and [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/154301/populating-monthly-report-with-new-data-each-month))

Is it so evident here that people are looking for suggestion on their code and it's not necessary to include it in the post?

Comment: You pretty much nailed it on the head in your last paragraph!

Comment: They're typically not *stellar*, and personally I tend to downvote code dumps, and code-dump questions are sometimes closed as *unclear what you're asking*.. but in general yes, "please provide feedback on any/all aspects of the code" is implied; any on-topic CR question's author *must* be open to constructive criticism on *any/all aspects of the code* they're presenting. How well they *present* that code varies... vote as you see fit ;-)

Comment: Also worth noting, CR question titles that *read like a question* (e.g. "How can I improve the performance of this code?", "How should I refactor this code?", "Can this code be further optimized?", etc.) are *especially* poor; they tell nothing about *what* the code is written to do. Hence good CR titles look like "Tic-Tac-Toe with AI" or "Fizz Buzz in reverse"; *great* titles look like "Merciless Tic-Tac-Toe AI" or "Zzub Zzif".